# about "who in the software world do you admire the most"?

Tags: discussion, polling

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545/who-in-the-software-world-do-you-admire-the-most) has hundreds of answers, many of which are probably dupes. I'm actually amazed that it's still alive, considering the "let's close them polls" of the last few months (weeks?). The question fits more in programmers.SE than here, but given their strictness, I don't even know if it will survive there. I personally find it constructive (though so many of the answers are of low quality, without any reason why Guido van Rossum is admired, for example).

So my question is, how come it's still alive?

Comment: Constructive to what end other than getting a list of names people fawn over?

Comment: Were the downvotes due to me saying the Question is constructive?

Answer (score 6):

Closed and deleted, I am not following how this belongs *or* is constructive anywhere.

> Who is the most popular person in class?

Who cares.

Comment: It was deleted by you twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545/who-in-the-software-world-do-you-admire-the-most

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/deleted-question-deleted-twice-by-same-user

Comment: @Justin :) I think that is a concurrency bug I clicked delete the exact same time someone else casted a delete vote

Comment: ...and somehow, you assimilated that delete vote for yourself? I'm using a site run by __Borg @waffles__?!