# Deleted question deleted 'twice' by same user

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

See the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545/who-in-the-software-world-do-you-admire-the-most

[image: Deleted twice]

It was recently deleted, but it somehow looks like it was deleted by the same mod twice.

Comment: He just really, really thought that question had to go. His conviction was recognized by the UI

Comment: This is probably a race condition of sorts. We've had a couple hiccups in the past where a moderator has voted to close something twice in a row - sometimes by accidental dual input. The worst of it was with migrations, though. Probably unrelated, but we are also having some weird acceptance things with two answers being accepted. I imagine that today is just a busy day for the server.

Comment: There are just two moderators with that name. ^^ <— might be a joke

Comment: Gasp! He must have voted to delete with a sockpuppet, realized his mistake, force-deleted as a mod and then merged the accounts!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Oh nice find.

Comment: My 2-year-old question just got closed as a duplicate of a 5-hour-old question. `>_<`