# Multiple deletion bug

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleted question deleted 'twice' by same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/deleted-question-deleted-twice-by-same-user)

When looking at [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818303/im-getting-segmentation-fault-in-parser-getdocument-using-xerces-for-c) recently that had been deleted by the owner, I spotted an interesting anomoly:

[image]

Not that it's serious, but you may want to look into it.

Comment: He was simply *super* ashamed of his question and the UI picked up on that. Good job, guys

Comment: @Pekka: "she", I think, since the name was changed (from a feminine name) to `supershame` shortly after the deletion, further proof that you're probably right :-)